# Symfony2 - String is converted into tinyint in the Database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Why is this property mapped as a integer type in the Database when I do `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`?:

```
const ORDINARY = 'ordinary';
const EXTRAORDINARY = 'extraordinary';
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="ordinariness")
 * @Constraints\NotNull
 * @Constraints\Choice(choices={"ordinary", "extraordinary"})
 */
private $ordinariness = self::ORDINARY;
```

I was having weird issues until I tried to modify the `ordinariness` value in the Database. Then I realized that the property has been mapped as a `tinyint`. Any idea of what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is fine. Everything should work. Are you sure that you don't inherit from this class and not override the property? What happens if you run: php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql ? What happens if you build schema from a scratch?

Comment: @Cyprian - If I do `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` I get `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.`. If I build from scratch I get the same result.

Comment: @Cyprian - Also seems there's nothing overriding this class (Convocation), as I do `grep -r "extends\sConvocation" src/` and no results are found.

Comment: Even if you drop whole database (from db level) and then build from scratch you still get tinyint? It would be really weird - therefore let's try to remove this property from you entity and check if the field is created in db after you rebuild schema again.

Comment: @Cyprian - I've already tried this without success. I'm really confused...

Comment: You've tried this - so after you remove this property - you don't have a column in db table. Is that right?

Comment: @Cyprian - The only way I found out to make it work is to change by hand the filed type in the database. But it is a really weird behavior.

Comment: @Cyprian - The most strange thing is that it works right in the remote server, when I update the database. I'm more confused than ever.

Comment: And what happens if you add the same property to another entity (copy-paste)? Is it also create tinyint column in the another table?